# Convert Curl Request

Tags: python-3.x, api, curl

would someone be able to convert this curl?

curl -X POST "https://api2.isbndb.com/books" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: special access key" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "isbns=9781492666868,9781616555719"

I did so like this:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'special access key',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = {
    'isbns': '9781492666868,9781616555719'
}

response = requests.post('https://api2.isbndb.com/books', headers=headers, data=data)
```

The results that i get from this are below:

```
print(response.json())
{'total': 0, 'requested': 1, 'data': []}
```

I do get the book data results I am looking for when I change my data dict to:

```
data = {
    'isbns': '9781492666868'
}
```

So, I am little confused on how to approach this. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn’t work?

**What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: That makes sense, I should have been more clear. I made some edits to the above question.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

when you set header *Content-Type* to *application/json*, instead of argument **data** you should use **json** argument

```
response = requests.post('https://api2.isbndb.com/books', headers=headers, json=data)
```

second option is to use data argument with **json.dumps**

```
response = requests.post('https://api2.isbndb.com/books', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

your case works when *Content-Type* is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*

Comment: Thanks for the answer jeffry_bo.  When i change the response to: response = requests.post('https://api2.isbndb.com/books', headers=headers, json=data) then i get a result of {'errorType': 'TypeError', 'errorMessage': 'event.body-json.split is not a function', 'trace': ['TypeError: event.body-json.split is not a function', '    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:15:38)', '    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)']}.  So i don't think this solves my problem.